# Linux file splitting

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am using sed to split a file in two

I have a file that has a custom separator "/-sep-/" and I want to split the file where the separator is

currently I have:

```
sed -n '1,/-sep-/ {p}' /export/data.temp > /export/data.sql.md5

sed -n '/-sep-/,$ {p}' /export/data.temp > /export/data.sql
```

but the file 1 contains /-sep-/ at the end and the file two begins with /-sep-/

how can I handle this?

note that on the file one I should remove a break line and the /-sep-/ and on the file 2 remove the /-sep-/ and a break line :S

Comment: Must use `sed`? For my sample input `csplit /export/data.temp '/-sep-/' '%.*%'` works, just the filenames can not be generated like in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse it: tell it what to **not** print instead.

```
sed '/-sep-/Q' /export/data.temp > /export/data.sql.md5
sed '1,/-sep-/d'/export/data.temp > /export/data.sql
```

(Regarding that *break line*, I did not understand it. A sample input would probably help.)

By the way, your original code needs only minor addition to do what you want:

```
sed -n '1,/-sep-/{/-sep-/!p}' /export/data.temp > /export/data.sql.md5
sed -n '/-sep-/,${/-sep-/!p}' /export/data.temp > /export/data.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat >testfile
a
a
a
a
/-sep-/
b
b
b
b
```

and then

```
$ csplit testfile '/-sep-/' '//'
8
8
8
$ head -n 999 xx*
==> xx00 <==
a
a
a
a

==> xx01 <==
/-sep-/

==> xx02 <==
b
b
b
b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/-sep-/q; p' /export/data.temp > /export/data.sql.md5
sed -n '/-sep-/,$ {p}' /export/data.temp | sed '1d' > /export/data.sql
```

Might be easier to do in one pass with awk:

```
awk -v out=/export/data.sql.md5 -v f2=/export/data.sql '
  /-sep-/ { out=f2; next}
  { print > out }
' /exourt/data.temp
```

Comment: This `awk` solution is very nice.